# Cube.js dimension and metrics validation

Tags: database, validation, metrics, dimension, cube.js

I was working on a project where we were using cube.js for query generation,I need some way to validate weather the selected metrics and dimensions are valid or not does anyone have idea on this.

I tried using some complex graphs to see weather there is a valid path between the provided dimensions and metrics but i could'nt come up with any solution.